# Fill nulls until certain column value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following time series dataframe. I would like to fill the missing values with the previous value. However i would only want to fill the missing values until a certain value is reached. This value is recorded in a different column. So the columns i wanna fill will be different for each row. How can i do this?

So, given this dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2 ,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan , 2009], [1, 3 , np.nan , np.nan , np.nan , 2010], [4, np.nan , 7 , np.nan,np.nan , 2011]], columns=[2007,2008,2009,2010,2011 , fill_until])
```

Input dataframe

```
2007    2008    2009    2010    2011  fill_until 
 1       2       NaN    NaN     NaN   2009
 1       3       NaN    NaN     NaN   2010
 4       Nan     7      NaN     NaN   2011
```

Output dataframe:

```
2007    2008    2009    2010    2011
 1       2       2      NaN      NaN
 1       3       3        3      NaN
 4       4       7        7        7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ffill` + `where` -

```
m = df.columns[:-1].values <= df.fill_until.values[:, None]
df.iloc[:, :-1].ffill(axis=1).where(m)

   2007  2008  2009  2010  2011
0   1.0   2.0   2.0   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN
2   4.0   4.0   7.0   7.0   7.0
```

---

**Details**

Use NumPy's broadcasting to obtain a mask of values to be filled upto based on the `fill_until` column.

```
m = df.columns[:-1].values <= df.fill_until.values[:, None]
```

Or,

```
m = (df.columns[:-1].values[:, None] <= df.fill_until.values).T
```

```
m    
array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Now, slice out all but the last column, and call `ffill` along the first axis -

```
i = df.iloc[:, :-1].ffill(axis=1)
i

   2007  2008  2009  2010  2011
0   1.0   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
1   1.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
2   4.0   4.0   7.0   7.0   7.0
```

Now, use the previously computed mask `m` to mask the values of `i` using `df.where` -

```
i.where(m)

   2007  2008  2009  2010  2011
0   1.0   2.0   2.0   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN
2   4.0   4.0   7.0   7.0   7.0
```

Alternatively, use `mask`, inverting `m` -

```
i.mask(~m)

   2007  2008  2009  2010  2011
0   1.0   2.0   2.0   NaN   NaN
1   1.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN
2   4.0   4.0   7.0   7.0   7.0
```

Comment: plus1, nice one ;)

Comment: @jezrael Same to you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

- first create index from column `fill_until`
- create mask by numpy broadcasting
- use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and apply [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with method `ffill` (same as `ffill`)
- last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and for same order of columns add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2 ,np.nan,np.nan,10 , 2009], 
                   [1, 3 , np.nan , np.nan , np.nan , 2010], 
                   [4, np.nan , 7 , np.nan,np.nan , 2011]], 
                   columns=[2007,2008,2009,2010,2011 , 'fill_until'])
print (df)
   2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  fill_until
0     1   2.0   NaN   NaN  10.0        2009
1     1   3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN        2010
2     4   NaN   7.0   NaN   NaN        2011

df1 = df.set_index('fill_until')
m = df1.columns.values <= df1.index.values[:, None]
print (m)
[[ True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]]

df =  df1.mask(m, df1.ffill(axis=1)).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  fill_until
0     1   2.0   2.0   NaN  10.0        2009
1     1   3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN        2010
2     4   4.0   7.0   7.0   7.0        2011
```

Comment: Hey, check out my answer, it's identical.

Comment: Yes, I check it, and no, it is different - mask + set_index + reindex + reset_index

Comment: My answer also has mask... if you scroll down. :)

Comment: OK. give me a sec

Comment: No worries, please take your time.

Comment: Yeah, I am fine with this. :-)